# I want to call this procedure and pass the variables that are fetched in the cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass these variables but getting error

[image]

**my code:**

```
 begin

 open CUR_SCENARIO_1;
 fetch CUR_SCENARIO_1 bulk collect
   into v_id, v_state, v_toc, v_sub, v_resp, v_pp_status limit 10;

FOR x in v_id.count()
SP_Create_original_record(v_id, v_state, v_toc, v_sub, v_resp, v_pps);
END LOOP;

end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As stated above, please share the error you are getting while execution.

Comment: Hey @NJInamdar... i have shared a link for the error please go through that.

Comment: From the code you posted, you are missing the keyword LOOP after the line `FOR x in v_id.count()`

Comment: Yeahhh that worked...my bad...thanks a lot all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a `Loop` keyword and a The starting and the ending value of the Loop.

```
FOR x in 1 .. v_id.count() loop
  SP_Create_original_record(v_id, v_state, v_toc, v_sub, v_resp, v_pps);
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to go a step further; nest the FOR loop in a "fetch loop". Without doing so you will process the first 10 rows from you cursor and the exit. If the cursor returns more, the additional will not be processed.

```
loop -- fetch loop
    fetch CUR_SCENARIO_1 bulk collect into v_id, ... limit 10;
    for x in 1..v_id.count()
    loop 
       ...  
    end loop ; 

    exit when v_id.count() < 10;
end loop;  -- fetch loop
```